# PHP with UTF-8 ok on OSX, not on Ubuntu

Tags: php, macos, ubuntu, encoding, utf-8

I'm building a PHP site on my Macbook (OSX) and am deploying it on a Ubuntu 12.04 server. I'm using similar versions of PHP (5.5.27 vs. 5.5.30) and nginx (1.6.2 vs. 1.8) on both. I've tried to follow UTF-8 best practices, such as using `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')` and `mb_http_output('UTF-8')`, as well as having `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` and `<meta type="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />` in my header. My data is correctly stored in both DBs as UTF-8 and when I query the database on the Ubuntu server, I can see non-standard characters, such as é.

Everything works fine on OSX, but the non-standard characters won't render to the browser on the Ubuntu machine. Things improve when I remove the `<meta type="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />` from the header. I'm not using PHP's `mb_` string functions anywhere, which I know could be causing some issues, but I don't see why things work fine on OSX and not Ubuntu.

Just wondering if anyone's ever noticed this before, or does anyone have a suggestion for something I can try to change/fix in my settings etc.? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean when using OS X / Ubuntu as the server or the client?

Comment: Open your page with Firefox, right click anywhere, and click on Page Info. You will see the Text Encoding as detected by the browser. This is useful to start debugging it. If it is correctly set as UTF8, then the problem is more probably on the storage. If it is not correct (say ISO8859-1) then it is about transmission (headers and nginx setting).

Comment: @GoatMaster I mean running ngnix on either my Macbook/OSX or server/Ubuntu. Client is OSX for both.

Comment: @Palantir it's definitely UTF-8 detected by the browser, in the headers and in storage. It could be an nginx setting alright, but any idea of what? The both use fairly similar vhost configs too.

Comment: One of the must be wrong :-) So the idea is to move step by step from the client back to PHP, then back to the storage, and finally back to the DB import or creation step (if you are importing a DB file, then maybe the encoding of that one is the problem!)

Comment: The weird thing is how the non-standard characters render correctly when I output them to the browser, but only when I remove the `<meta type="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />` line from the <head>. They're definitely stored in and retrieved from the DB correctly. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

OK, after trying loads of different things, this is what worked for me.

1. My default character set and collation for the database were latin1, so changed them to utf8mb4:

   ALTER DATABASE db_name
       CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
       DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
       COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
       DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
       ;

   ALTER TABLE tbl_name
       DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
       COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
       ;
2. Run SQL `SET NAMES utf8mb4;` every time I instantiate a DB connection

At this point I was sending character data correctly to the browser, but `iconv` with `//TRANSLIT` was dropping non alphabetical characters, so to fix that:

3. At the top of my main config PHP file I added `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8');`